# Por que a variável x do tipo double sempre imprime o mesmo valor ERRADO em notação científica?

Tags: c, variáveis, float, inteiros, double

Neste primeiro exemplo gostaria de saber por que a variável x lida em double, quando é formatada pela função "printf()" não exibe o valor corretamente, e todas as vezes o valor é o mesmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double x;

    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("%e", x);

    return 0;
}
```

2) Uma variável x do tipo float, quando impressa na tela no formato inteiro sempre dará 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float x;

    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

3) Por que a variável x do tipo inteiro quando impressa no formato double é 0 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("%f", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O `scanf` para `double` não é usando `%f` e família, mas `%lf` e família

Comment: Sobre dois e três, não há coerção de tipo, nem de ponto flutuante para inteiro nem o contrário, então o valor vai ser bem caótico, pois o `printf` fará interpretação dos bytes passados como sendo de outro tipo

Comment: E para complementar o que o @JeffersonQuesado disse um double/float tem o expoente guardado nos bits de maior peso (normalmente 8) logo e maior parte dos valores são quantificados para zero pois não geram informação até esses bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então - como está nos comentários: essas funções `printf` e `scanf` **não tem** como saber qual é o tipo de argumento que você está passando para elas a partir do tipo declarado da variável.

Elas só "adivinham" que tipo de dado foi passado, ou o que devem copiar para a variável (no caso do scanf), a partir justamente da string de formatação.

Então quando você, no caso 3, diz para para o `printf` que vai passar um número do tipo float, ele vai pegar os bytes correspondents da pilha de parâmetros e trata-los como um [double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395747/108205). (Veja abaixo por que um double e não um float).  E os valores internos desses bytes são muito diferentes para um float e um inteiro de 4 bytes.

Da mesma forma para o double, ao usar o `scanf` você tem que dizer se a variável que vai preencher é um "double" ou um "float" - o segundo caso usa os formatos `%f`, `%e` ou `%g` mas sempre [preenche apenas 4 bytes na memória alvo com os bytes correspondentes a um float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Para o `scanf` funcionar com um `double`, é necessário usar o modificador `l` no formato: `%lf`, `%le`, `%lg`.

O que confunde é que o próprio compilador, devido à *especificação* da linguagem C [sempre vai transformar um `float` em um `double` automaticamente quando for chamada uma função de parâmetros variáveis.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395747/108205)

Então na verdade o `%f` (e `%e`) no printf sempre vão lidar com doubles (e usar 8 bytes da pilha de argumentos), mesmo que no seu código você escreva que está passando um float. (e sim, os códigos portanto são diferentes dos usados pelo `scanf`).

Em C é necessário entender bem como os diferentes tipos de dados são representados na memória, e não pode haver sequer um erro. Por exemplo, se ao invés dos exemplos que você passou, tentasse imprimir uma variável `int` usando a formatação `%f`, o seu programa poderia terminar com uma falha de segmentação - já que o `printf` vai querer consumir 8 bytes de argumento onde só há 4. Em linguagens dinâmicas com um nível de abstração maior, como Javascript, Python, PHP e Ruby, esses problemas de conversão exata do dado para sua representação interna em geral são tratados pela própria linguagem. Outras linguagens estáticas como C#, go, Java, etc... vão ter mecanismos melhores para detectar esse tipo de problema no momento da compilação. Mas em C, é só você e a CPU. :-)

Comment: Só por curiosidade, se o _endianess_ fosse distinto, os `printf`s continuariam com os mesmos resultados?

Comment: Não. Só quando os dados tiverem o mesmo tamanho. Como num dos casos o erro está na string de formatação para o scanf, por exemplo, 4 bytes diferentes da variável double seram preenchidos pelo scanf com `%f` (em vez do correto `%lf`) - e nos prints, a impressão de "ints" passando um double também pegaria 4 bytes diferentes.